# Can I hide from visitors my questions and answers activity?

Tags: support, profile-page, privacy

I mean, especially from visitors who are not signed in but also from the other users.

Comment: You're trying to hide your math questions from your teacher?

Comment: No, from my colleagues.

Comment: it's not important:) it was more like a curiosity:)

Comment: Even if you could, someone could trivially search for posts made by you. When we go to a profile page, the search box is prefilled with the user: xyz part, so just add is:q or is:a and fire away

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible to hide your questions and answers or their activity from anyone, even from anonymous users.

Though, you can request to unlink a post of your own from your account (Flag it then, or as mods may not have this magic ability, use [the contact form](/contact)). In this case, you lose the rep you got with this post, the post is entirely removed from your profile page (for absolutely anyone, including you), and the post owner is marked as "anon". But you don't lose badges the post have given you. [Example of such an unlinked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4036868).

(Also, I wouldn't support a request to make such a feature, at least because Q&A is the purpose of Stack Exchange, and making questions&answers of yours hidden is somewhat against the intents)

Comment: Hi! Unless I'm mistaken, it appears that there are comments in your example of an unlinked post which have the name of the post author. If I'm correct, it may be worth noting that if a user wants to make their post completely anonymous, they might want to delete any comments containing their username. Just a thought!

Comment: @Sue a good idea. But in the example, I dont see such comments...

Comment: Thanks. Just because I saw names, I shouldn't have assumed any were the post auther. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

Nope, anyone can see any of your questions or answer, with or without an account.

However, you [can "hide" communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current) to a certain extent (the mods still see all the communities you are member of, and the network profile provides the info of all your communities for anyone), by looking at the sidebar in your profile.